Azure Machine Leraning Compute Cluster User Assigned Identities
I'm having a hard time to understand how User assigned identity works on Compute Clusters on Compute Clusters.
Today, I have a Compute Instance with a User assigned identity that will connect to other Azure services likes CosmosDB, Databricks and much more. So the User Identity has RBAC roles to it and also a SP made inside Databricks since it can not be synced with ADD.
So this work correclty, but when I want to launch a compute cluster from my compute instance, I user Azure SDK v2 to launch it. I tried to add a UserIdentityConfiguration()  to the command but when checking on the raw yml file configuration of the compute cluster, I see that the Identity is set to null
"runDefinition": {
        "script": null,
        "command": "python main.py",
        "useAbsolutePath": false,
        "arguments": [],
        "sourceDirectoryDataStore": null,
        "framework": "Python",
        "communicator": "None",
        "target": "cpu-2-16",
        "dataReferences": {},
        "data": {},
        "outputData": {},
        "datacaches": [],
        "jobName": null,
        "maxRunDurationSeconds": null,
        "nodeCount": 1,
        "instanceTypes": [],
        "priority": null,
        "credentialPassthrough": true,
        "identity": null,

I based my code like this example repo: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/211d3450211c26e95c6f40b4e01bd3adf5077774/articles/machine-learning/how-to-use-serverless-compute.md?plain=1#L93
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
# Get a handle to the workspace. You can find the info on the workspace tab on ml.azure.com
ml_client = MLClient(
    credential=credential,
    subscription_id="<Azure subscription id>", 
    resource_group_name="<Azure resource group>",
    workspace_name="<Azure Machine Learning Workspace>",
)
job = command(
    command="echo 'hello world'",
    environment="AzureML-sklearn-1.0-ubuntu20.04-py38-cpu@latest",
    identity=UserIdentityConfiguration(),
)
# submit the command job
ml_client.create_or_update(job)

In the definition of the compute cluster, I do have the User Assigned Identity:

Also in my compute instance, I have the same User Assigned Identity (AZGRE........)
So how do I make my compute cluster take the identity of my compute instance? Or even take the Identity of the user running the code if he did an az login ?

You have 2 user assigned identity  in your cluster?

you given raw json defination.. What do you see in yaml job defination?

yes I have multiple assigned identity on my compute cluster. The goal is that we have multiple users that use small compute instances to develop. Then they launch their code on GPU based compute cluster. So the user managed identities of the users are defined in each compute clusters.

But this code is for server less compute also the documentation you provided.

I think I found a solution, using ManagedIdentityConfiguration and using the compute instance info. identity = ManagedIdentityConfiguration(os.environ.get("DEFAULT_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID", None)). The remaining issue is that if the user launches from it's own computer, he doesn't have the DEFAULT_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID and will take a the first user assigned identity in the list of compute cluster.

Yeah i am about to post the solution with additional information

I have provided solution which applies to serverless compute. if you are using on custom cluster give ManagedIdentityConfiguration(client_id) and in command job configure compute as your cluster.

I did not found the documentation for non serverless compute cluster. Today I am not using serverless. How would I managed to launch a compute cluster with a real Identity? For example, I do az login on my computer (so no Managed ID) and launch the compute cluster from my computer.

According to this documentation UserIdentityConfiguration Passthrough your Microsoft Entra identity, that is the reason you get null in raw json defination but if you check in yaml defination you can see the UserIdentity
.
So, you need to use ManagedIdentityConfiguration which is assigned while creating ml workspace itself.

Try below.
job = command(
    command="echo 'hello world'",
    environment="AzureML-sklearn-1.0-ubuntu20.04-py38-cpu@latest",
    identity=ManagedIdentityConfiguration(),
)

Output:
In raw json

In yaml

Make sure you required roles and permission.
EDIT
command_job = command(
    code="./src",
    command="python main.py --iris-csv ${{inputs.iris_csv}} --learning-rate ${{inputs.learning_rate}} --boosting ${{inputs.boosting}}",
    environment="AzureML-lightgbm-3.2-ubuntu18.04-py37-cpu@latest",
    inputs={
        "iris_csv": Input(
            type="uri_file",
            path="https://azuremlexamples.blob.core.windows.net/datasets/iris.csv",
        ),
        "learning_rate": 0.9,
        "boosting": "gbdt",
    },
    compute="cpu-cluster",
    identity=ManagedIdentityConfiguration(<client_id>)
)

As given in the above code you give compute option mentioning your new cluster created with user identity.
Learn more about command job here

Sadly I cannot recreate a new Workspace with User Assigned Identity, I'm not the owner of this ressource. So I have to specify the clientId inside ManagedIdentityConfiguration

For serverless that doesn't work.  go with cluster.

@BeGreen updated solution for cluster. kindly check it.

Last question, is it possible to get the clientId of a manged identity from the name of the user assigned identity? Because sometimes, the environment wont have the DEFAULT_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID env variable

I found a solution using ManagedServiceIdentityClient

Manually in portal you can copy and provide it directly. When you enabled the user managed identity that cluster will always have DEFAULT_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID but when using multiple identities you need to provide the client id manually to ManagedIdentityConfiguration
